# Pass array of string in parameter request - swift 5

Tags: arrays, json, swift, alamofire

Pass array of string in parameter request - swift 5. I want to send an array in a parameter from an alamofire request.

This is the request on Postman:

[image]

[image]
This is my solution:

```
var Token : String?
       var  tasksMO = [NSManagedObject]()
       let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ConfirmActivationEntity")
       do {
           let results = try pe.context.fetch(request)
           tasksMO = results as! [NSManagedObject]
           for taskmo in tasksMO {
               Token = (taskmo.value(forKey: "access_token")  as! String )
           }
           print("assbil")
       } catch {
           print("fild")
       }
 print(" Token :\(Token!)")
let levels  : [String]  = ["+972569431827","+972598110437","+972592923343","3555656","00970567163651","258258"]

let paramsJSON = JSON(levels)
debugPrint(paramsJSON)
let parameters : [String : Any] = ["contacts":paramsJSON,"platform":2]


 let headers : HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(Token!)","Accept-Language" : Locale.current.languageCode ?? "ar", "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept" : "application/json"]

guard let url = URL(string: "\(UrlApi.url)\(UrlApi.contactsPost)") else { return }

   sdLoader.startAnimating(atView: self.view)
   Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
     if let error = response.error {
           print(error)
           return
       }

       if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
        print(status)
        print(response.result.value!)
         switch(status){
           case 200:

        self.sdLoader.stopAnimation()
         do{
              let decoder = JSONDecoder()
              let userResultDec = try decoder.decode(ContactsJSON.self, from: response.data!)
              decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
               if userResultDec.status == true {

                print(userResultDec.items)

               } else if userResultDec.status == false {
                   self.showAlert(title: "رسالة", message: "هناك خطا بالمعلومات المدخلة", style: .alert)
           }


          }  catch let parsingError {
               print("Error", parsingError)
               MessageBox.Show(Message: " \(parsingError) , خطأ في السيرفير ", MyVC: self)
          }
           case 401 :
            self.sdLoader.stopAnimation()
              print("error with response status: \(status)")
              print("خطأ في السيرفير")
              MessageBox.Show(Message: "error with response status: \(status) , خطأ في السيرفير ", MyVC: self)
           case 404 :
            self.sdLoader.stopAnimation()
              print("error with response status: \(status)")
              print("خطأ في السيرفير")
              MessageBox.Show(Message: "error with response status: \(status) , خطأ في السيرفير ", MyVC: self)

         case 500:
              MessageBox.Show(Message: "error with response status: \(status) , خطأ في السيرفير ", MyVC: self)
            default:
             print("Error")

           }
       }
    }
```

The problem is:
The items in the array do not appear in the reference response from the server

I am using the Alamofire pod and the SwiftyJson pod with iOS 13, Swift 5, and Xcode 11.

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with application/x-www-form-urlencoded conversations in Alamofire/Swift. It does work in Postman way. Postman automatically converts your array but swift does not.

```
struct ArrayEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
  func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
    var request = try URLEncoding().encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
    request.url = URL(string: request.url!.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "%5B%5D=", with: "="))
    return request
  }
}
```

Comment: How to use it in the REQUEST ??

Answer (score 0):

Please try this example :

```
var apiRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
apiRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
apiRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let levels = ["+972569431827","+972598110437","+972592923343","3555656","00970567163651","258258"]

apiRequest.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values)

Alamofire.request(apiRequest)
    .responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)

            if let data = response.data, let responseStr = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(responseStr)
            }
        case .success(let responseValue):
            print(responseValue)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I make the request post by sending an array: (Alamofire v5)

```
let apiInputs = [
    "input1": "example1",    
    "input2": "example2",
    "input3": "example3",
    "inputN": "exampleN",
]

AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    for (key, value) in apiInputs {
        multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)                                        } // End for multipart form data.
        }, to: "https://example.com/api")
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
}
```

I leave you the official documentation:

[Alamofire/MultipartFormData](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#uploading-multipart-form-data)